# Unable to save/update the record into db in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying the update the record for the columns IsValid and Comments in rails, but doesn't get updated in backend or any error:

**Below is my parameters result:**

```
Started PATCH "/metrics/1" for 
Processing by MetricsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"1oC/1UdAaTPUepy1zIjO1x6n67Th/pdcnvYJH95cB63tZts9d135JIK4MzQD2/pdPoRKnUKXIc0ZI9MQZkjfNQ==", 
  "metrics_controller"=>{"IsValid"=>"False", "Comments"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"1"}
  Metric Load (75.1ms)  SELECT  `Threshold`.* FROM `Threshold` WHERE `Threshold`.`ID` = 1 LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, metrics_controller, commit, id
   (75.7ms)  BEGIN
   (75.1ms)  COMMIT
```

[image]

**update method in controller:**

```
 def update
        @metric = Metric.find(params[:id])
        #if(@metric.update(post_params))
        if(@metric.update_attributes(post_params))
          redirect_to metrics_path
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
      end
       private def post_params
    params.permit(:Metric, :WI, :Value, :UT, :Score, :IsValid, :UserName, :Comments)
  end
```

**If I update post_params method with the below code it is throwing error:**

```
private def post_params
    params.require(:metric).permit(:Metric, :WI, :Value, :UT, :Score, :IsValid, :UserName, :Comments)
  end
```

Comment: You need to leave the post_params method in as it permits the parameters. Can you posy what error message occurs when you try and update please?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like your header's params are send as body. How do you call update method? Ajax async call? Html/Rails form? could you update your answer?

Comment: Hi @Mark , I don't get any error but the data doesn't get saved in db

Comment: @MallelaSriPrakash replace if(@metric.update_attributes(post_params)) with if(@metric.update_attributes!(post_params)) please, the server will then throw an error and explain what is going wrong

Comment: @Mark As you have said, I have replaced it. But still I don't get any error while updating. But, when I changed the text as this if(@metric.update_attributes(!post_params)) then I get this error: 
**When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.**

Comment: The exclamation mark goes before the brackets:

Comment: if(@metric.update_attributes!(post_params))

Comment: Yes @Mike, that's what I said in my earlier post. Using this, if(@metric.update_attributes!(post_params)) I don't get any error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183645/discussion-between-mallela-sriprakash-and-mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The params that are coming from the request (from the logs) are :

```
{
  "utf8"=>"âœ“",
  "authenticity_token"=>"1oC/1UdAaTPUepy1zIjO1x6n67Th..",
  "metrics_controller"=> {
    "IsValid"=>"False",
    "Comments"=>"1"
  },
  "commit"=>"Save",
  "id"=>"1"
}
```

So the key `isValid` is under  the key `metrics_controller`.
Then, with this kind of coming data, in your controller, you should call

```
params
  .require(:metrics_controller)
  .permit(:IsValid, :Comments, :id)
```

You should take care of the naming convention (snake_case instead of CamelCase), but the most important thing is that the form that is responsible of this request should name inputs accordingly to what's your controller expect.

Then, you should name form elements with something like (according to your screenshot)

```
<select name="metric[is_valid]">
  <option value="1">Yes</option>
  <option value="0">No</option>
</select>
```

With that kind of naming, data will be scoped in key `metric` instead of `metric_controller`, and it'll go through strong params.

Answer (score 1):

By convention in ruby, and rails, you should almost always use `snake_case` for methods and variables; not `CamelCase`.

You haven't quite provided enough information for me to say this with 100% certainty (in particular, what is the database schema for the `metrics` table?), but that is almost certainly the cause of the problem here.

Your `Metric` class likely has attributes such as `value`, `score`, `is_valid`, etc. But you are trying to update attributes named `Comments` and `IsValid`. These attributes do not exist, so nothing gets updated.

---

Change your view to use `snake_case`, and permit variables in `snake_case`; then it should work. It would be *possible* to make it work using `CamelCase` like you've done here, but that's against conventions - so would require more effort.

Comment: I agree that the first step is to get the naming conventions fixed in this code. Hopefully whatever is calling this update method is not passing the params as CamelCase. If so that should be fixed as well. This is the second question I've seen this week where not following Rails' naming convention has caused an app to not work.

Comment: @Dan *"Hopefully whatever is calling this update method is not passing the params as CamelCase"* -- It looks like it is, though! From the OP's console log: `"metrics_controller"=>{"IsValid"=>"False", "Comments"=>"1"}`.

Comment: yikes, I see that now. It would be nice to see the schema to see how far reaching this unconventional naming is. It's possible the DB fields **are** camel case. Ultimately, the OP just needs to be consistent across all parts of his app. It's possible he is and case isn't the issue...

Answer (score 0):

As @Tom Lord mentioned, the case of your parameters looks suspicious and might be causing your problem. If you could provide your schema for the `metrics` table that will help us help you.

Rails will always work at its best when you follow the naming conventions. This most importantly includes using the correct case and singular/plural names.

This is how I'd expect your code to look if it were written the Rails way:

```
def update
  @metric = Metric.find(params[:id])
  if @metric.update(post_params)
    redirect_to metrics_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private 

def post_params
  params.permit(:metric, :wi, :value, :ut, :score, :is_valid, :user_name, :comments)
end
```